Python telegram bot for dash
I work as an operator in a shooting gallery. Before I give out toys, I take pictures of them and post them in a telegram bot with the name "Cat ak", at the end of the day I count how many different toys were given out. I wanted to write a bot that, by clicking on the button, gives statistics on the toys issued, but I have constant errors. I hope you can help me. Please describe all the fixes, including the python-telegram-bot version
`
 from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, 
 MessageHandler, 
 Filters
 import logging

# Настройка логирования
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s 
 - %(message)s',
                level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

stats = {}

# Обработчик команды /start
def start(update, context):
update.message.reply_text('Привет! Отправьте мне фото игрушки с 
названием в формате "Название ак".')

# Обработчик для получения фото и названия игрушки
def get_toy(update, context):
photo_file = update.message.photo[-1].get_file()
photo_file.download('photo.jpg')

toy_name = update.message.caption.lower()
if toy_name in stats:
    stats[toy_name] += 1
else:
    stats[toy_name] = 1

# Обработчик для отображения статистики
def show_stats(update, context):
stats_str = ''
for toy_name, count in stats.items():
    stats_str += f'{toy_name}: {count}\n'

update.message.reply_text(stats_str)

def main():
# Создаем Updater и передаем ему токен бота
updater = Updater("YOUR_BOT_TOKEN", use_context=True)

# Получаем диспетчер для зарегистрированных обработчиков
dp = updater.dispatcher

# Регистрируем обработчики команд
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("stats", show_stats))

# Регистрируем обработчик для получения фото и названия игрушки
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.photo & 
 (~Filters.command), 
 get_toy))

# Запускаем бота
updater.start_polling()

# Запускаем бесконечный цикл для работы бота
updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()

`

Please ensure your whole question is in English, as Stack Overflow is an English-only site. The code does not need to be in English, but all other parts of the question must be.
